# Effect of word length on the popularity of tweets using Python?

Tags: python, twitter

- *First, you will write tweet_length
  The function will take one parameter tweet, a string that represents a tweet
  The function will return an integer, the number of words in that tweet.*
- *Second, you will write average_tweet_length
  The function will take one parameter tweet_list, a list of strings (where each string represents a tweet)
  The function will return a float, the average word length of the list of tweets.*
- *Third, you will write get_long_tweets
  The function will take one parameter tweet_list, a list of strings (where each string represents a tweet)
  The function will return a list of the "long" tweets (any tweet longer than the average tweet length in tweet_list).*

This is a very rough skeletal outline:

```py
def tweet_length(tweet):
    return len(tweet)

print(tweet_length("Hello"))


def average_tweet_length(tweet_list):
    for tweet in range(len(tweet_list)):
        average = int(tweet_list[tweet]) / (len(tweet_list)) 
        return average

print(average_tweet_length(['Hello', 'Greetings', 'Hiiii', "Tweet"]))


def get_long_tweets(tweet_list):
    if len(tweet_list) > average:
        return tweet_list
```

And after this I am stuck as I keep getting error.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes:

1. This is probably why you get an error. You are trying to access the `average` variable in the `get_long_tweets()`-Function, but it's not defined outside the `average_tweet_length()`-Function, because you are only printing it. And not storing the return value as `average`
2. The calculation in `average_tweet_length()` is wrong. You are returning the  average in the first iteration. If the length of the first tweet would be 5 and you had 10 tweets, you would return instantly 5/10. Additionaly you can not use `int()` to get the length of a tweet. You can use `len(tweet)`. To calculate the average properly you can use the `sum`-Function:
   `return sum([len(tweet) for tweet in tweet_list])/len(tweet_list)`